# Resin Server - Can't install into Eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, centos, resin

I'm using CentOS 6.4. I have downloaded Resin server from the [this official website](http://www.caucho.com/download/). I have the folder in /home/admin/.  I followed [this site](http://wiki3.caucho.com/Eclipse#Installing_from_the_Resin_Eclipse_plugin_update_site_.28Helios_and_above.29) for adding resin server into Eclipse. but couldn't able to see resin option. Is there any way to add resin server into Eclipse. ?

> **UPDATE**

I configured network connections settings under windows->preferences-> general->Network connection –

Comment: Did you follow this ? `Help->Install New Software->Add...`. In the `Add Repository` dialog, enter a name and the location for the Resin Eclipse plugin website (http://www.caucho.com/eclipse/).

Comment: yes I did.. @tailorBird. It shows, "Could not find any in caucho.com/eclipse" . 
Having a doubt. Should I need to change proxy settings in network connection in Window-> preferences.

Comment: How? Made any changes in preferences?

Comment: I configured network connections settings under windows->preferences-> general->Network connection